How to get 2 linux process ids created on a single line command using shell script
I have a command to start tcpdump on a timeout. So I have a shell script written to start this process and give the executor of the shell script the process ids created in the shell script. My shell script looks like
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT_DURATION=3600
TIMEOUT=${v_TIMEOUT:-$TIMEOUT_DURATION}
FILTER=${v_FILTER:-} # make sure this parameter is URI encoded if it has special symbols inside filter
FILENAME=$(date +%s).log
TCPDUMP_PID=$(timeout 3600 tcpdump -i eth0 -w $FILENAME $FILTER > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!)

echo "TCPDUMP_PID=$TCPDUMP_PID"

But I get only the process id of the tcpdump but not the timeout. I would like to get the process id of both the processes and echo it in the script so that the executor can use them to kill the 2 processes at a later point of time.
I dont want to kill all the processes using
pkill tcpdump; pkill timeout; 

here. I would like to kill only using the process id.
The 2 processes that spawn on running the above script looks like

I receive only 21 on the TCPDUMP_ID and not the 23.
How is this achievable?

PARENTPID=$(timeout ... & echo $!); pgrep -P $PARENTPID

You should be getting the PID of the timeout process, not tcpdump. The shell can only get the PID of its direct child, it doesn't know anything about grandchildren.

BTW, there's no need for the command substitution. Just do timeout tcpdump ... & TIMEOUT_PID=$!

Tangentially, don't use uppercase for your private variables

It would go further than "Tangentially" and simply say Don't Use UPPERCASE variable names -- uppercase is reserved for environment and bash system variables. (avoid learning bad scripting practices -- habits are hard to break...) If your boss/instructor is encouraging their use -- may want to gently provide them with the link above.

@Barmer Actually when you see the screenshot, $! doesnt give the PID of the timeout process but the PID of the tcpdump process which is 21
